# How do I do to get a random text from internet in a certain language selected from a spinner in Android?

Tags: android, rss

Can I access RSS feeds in a certain language using code? or is there a better way to get random text from internet? I searched but there's no info on this....I want the user to select in a Spinner "French" for example and go to a random source of information on that language and present the text to the user

Comment: So you want to load a random piece of text from the internet, in a specified language?

Comment: Yes, I want to connect, get a random piece of code from an RSS feed or somewhere else  in a certain language and put it in a texview